# Doctrine throws Fatal Error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

A website that works perfectly fine on a local server (XAMPP), but after being moved to the live hosting Doctrine is throwing an error ( only in one place on the website), as a response from a POST request to the SERVER:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/tmp/__CG__EntitiesEcomProducts.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [SERVER PATH]/php/Vendors/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 223
[24-Jan-2018 23:51:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/tmp/__CG__EntitiesEcomProducts.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in [SERVER PATH]/php/Vendors/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 223
```

Checked all the permissions with the Hosting admins.

I am NOT using Symfony.

PHP version on the hosting is 7.1 both on localhost and the live hosting.

**UPD2.**
It's not particular Entities that throw the error - it's all the `@ManyToOne` relations in them.

**UPD.** 
I reduced the code to initializing Doctrine and running the same code as traced by the error:

```
$ItemOption= $this->EntityManager->getRepository($this->Settings->Ecom->get('repos')[3])->findOneById(1);
```

Then this Entity throws the error:

```
class EcomProductsPrices{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer")  @GeneratedValue  **/
    protected $id;

    /**  @Column(type="string")  **/
    protected $title;

    /**  @Column(type="float",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $price;

    /**  @Column(type="float",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $discount;

    /**  @Column(type="integer",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $discountAfter;


    /**  
     *  @ManyToOne(targetEntity="EcomProducts", inversedBy="EcomProductsPrices",cascade={ "persist"} )
     *   
    **/
        protected $EcomProducts;
    /**  
     *  @OneToMany(targetEntity="EcomCart", mappedBy="EcomProductsPrices",cascade={ "persist"} ) 
    **/
    protected $EcomCart;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->EcomCart = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title){
        $this->title = $title;
    }
public function getPrice(){
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice($price=NULL){
        $this->price = $price;
    }
public function getDiscount(){
        return $this->discount;
    }

    public function setDiscount($discount=NULL){
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
public function getDiscountAfter(){
        return $this->discountAfter;
    }

    public function setDiscountAfter($discountAfter=NULL){
        $this->discountAfter = $discountAfter;
    }

        public function getEcomProducts(){
        return $this->EcomProducts;
    }

    public function setEcomProducts(EcomProducts $EcomProducts){       
        $this->EcomProducts = $EcomProducts;
    }





    public function RemoveEcomProducts(EcomProducts $EcomProducts){
            $this->EcomProducts=NULL;            

    }

    public function clearEcomProducts(){
        $this->EcomProducts->clear();
    }
      public function getEcomCart(){
        return $this->EcomCart;
    }

    public function setEcomCart(EcomCart $EcomCart){       
        if(is_array($EcomCart)){
            foreach($EcomCart as $Join){
                if(is_int($Join)){
                    $Join=$this->Kernel->EntityManager->getRepository($this->Kernel->Settings->ICatcher->get('php.entities-namespaces')[0].'EcomCart')->findOneById($Join);
                }
                if(!$this->EcomCart->contains($EcomCart)){
                    $this->EcomCart[] = $EcomCart;
                    $EcomCart->setEcomProductsPrices($this);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!$this->EcomCart->contains($EcomCart)){
                    $this->EcomCart[] = $EcomCart;
                    $EcomCart->setEcomProductsPrices($this);
            }
        }
    }



    public function RemoveEcomCart(EcomCart $EcomCart){
        if($this->EcomCart->contains($EcomCart)){
            $this->EcomCart->removeElement($EcomCart);
            $EcomCart->RemoveEcomProductsPrices($this);
        }
    }

    public function clearEcomCart(){
        $this->EcomCart->clear();
    }





    /** @PrePersist */
    public function preCreate(){
    }

    /** @preUpdate */
    public function preUpdate(){
    }

    /** @preRemove */
    public function preRemove(){
    }
}
```

The error is related to the join EcomProducts - this is what is the offending Entity shown in Doctrine `AbstractProxyFactor`

But when I change to find one in this Entity - there is no error:

```
class EcomOrder{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer")  @GeneratedValue  **/
    protected $id;

    /**  @Column(type="string",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $fullName;

    /**  @Column(type="string",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $address1;

    /**  @Column(type="string",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $address2;

    /**  @Column(type="string",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $promocode;

    /**  @Column(type="string",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $postcode;

    /**  @Column(type="float",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $deliveryPrice;

    /**  @Column(type="boolean",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $paid;

    /**  @Column(type="boolean",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $paypalReturned;

    /**  @Column(type="boolean",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $delivered;

    /**  @Column(type="datetime",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $dateCreated;

    /**  @Column(type="datetime",nullable=TRUE)  **/
    protected $dateUpdated;


    /**  
     *  @OneToMany(targetEntity="EcomCart", mappedBy="EcomOrder",cascade={ "persist"} ) 
    **/
    protected $EcomCart;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->EcomCart = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

public function getFullName(){
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    public function setFullName($fullName=NULL){
        $this->fullName = $fullName;
    }
public function getAddress1(){
        return $this->address1;
    }

    public function setAddress1($address1=NULL){
        $this->address1 = $address1;
    }
public function getAddress2(){
        return $this->address2;
    }

    public function setAddress2($address2=NULL){
        $this->address2 = $address2;
    }
public function getPromocode(){
        return $this->promocode;
    }

    public function setPromocode($promocode=NULL){
        $this->promocode = $promocode;
    }
public function getPostcode(){
        return $this->postcode;
    }

    public function setPostcode($postcode=NULL){
        $this->postcode = $postcode;
    }
public function getDeliveryPrice(){
        return $this->deliveryPrice;
    }

    public function setDeliveryPrice($deliveryPrice=NULL){
        $this->deliveryPrice = $deliveryPrice;
    }
public function getPaid(){
        return $this->paid;
    }

    public function setPaid($paid=NULL){
        $this->paid = $paid;
    }
public function getPaypalReturned(){
        return $this->paypalReturned;
    }

    public function setPaypalReturned($paypalReturned=NULL){
        $this->paypalReturned = $paypalReturned;
    }
public function getDelivered(){
        return $this->delivered;
    }

    public function setDelivered($delivered=NULL){
        $this->delivered = $delivered;
    }
public function getDateCreated(){
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated=NULL){
        if($dateCreated==NULL){
            $this->dateCreated = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
        }
        else{
            $this->dateCreated=$dateCreated;
        }
    }
public function getDateUpdated(){
        return $this->dateUpdated;
    }

    public function setDateUpdated($dateUpdated=NULL){
        if($dateUpdated==NULL){
            $this->dateUpdated = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
        }
        else{
            $this->dateUpdated=$dateUpdated;
        }
    }

        public function getEcomCart(){
        return $this->EcomCart;
    }

    public function setEcomCart(EcomCart $EcomCart){       
        if(is_array($EcomCart)){
            foreach($EcomCart as $Join){
                if(is_int($Join)){
                    $Join=$this->Kernel->EntityManager->getRepository($this->Kernel->Settings->ICatcher->get('php.entities-namespaces')[0].'EcomCart')->findOneById($Join);
                }
                if(!$this->EcomCart->contains($EcomCart)){
                    $this->EcomCart[] = $EcomCart;
                    $EcomCart->setEcomOrder($this);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!$this->EcomCart->contains($EcomCart)){
                    $this->EcomCart[] = $EcomCart;
                    $EcomCart->setEcomOrder($this);
            }
        }
    }



    public function RemoveEcomCart(EcomCart $EcomCart){
        if($this->EcomCart->contains($EcomCart)){
            $this->EcomCart->removeElement($EcomCart);
            $EcomCart->RemoveEcomOrder($this);
        }
    }

    public function clearEcomCart(){
        $this->EcomCart->clear();
    }





    /** @PrePersist */
    public function preCreate(){
        $this->setDateCreated();
    }

    /** @preUpdate */
    public function preUpdate(){
        $this->setDateUpdated();
    }

    /** @preRemove */
    public function preRemove(){
    }
}
```

**SAME** code for **BOTH** entities works without any errors on the localhost (XAMPP, PHP7.1, Windows). The problem is on the live host (PHP7.1, Linux).

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by adding this line to the configuration of Doctrine:

```
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(TRUE);
```

But why it was working without it on the localhost is still a mystery.